# django model with IpAddressField throws error in syncdb

Tags: python, django, model, ip, field

I've got a `models.py` file with following class defined:

```
from django.db import models
from bands.models import Genre, Song

class Lyric(models.Model):
    """A music lyric"""
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'lyric'
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre)
    song = models.ForeignKey(Song,unique=True)
    lyric_text = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "\"" + self.title + "\" by " + self.author
    def lyric_short(self, length=100):
        return self.lyric_text[:length] + "..."

class LyricComment(models.Model):
    """Comment on a lyric"""
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'lyric_comment'
    lyric = models.ForeignKey(Lyric)
    text = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    ip = models.IpAddressField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "\"" + self.text[:10] + "...\" by " + self.author
    def text_short(self, length=100):
        return self.text[:length] + "..."
```

When running:

```
$ python manage.py syncdb
```

the following error is thrown:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'IpAddressField'
```

What is wrong with `ip = models.IpAddressField()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's spelled `IPAddressField`, big `P`.

Comment: what a shame ;) precisely - this was it.

Answer (score 1):

This is spelling mistake .

change `ip = models.IpAddressField()`  to `ip = models.IPAddressField()`